# 10k flag tools no longer exclude posts I've already reviewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

The 10k flag tools no longer exclude posts I've already reviewed.

For example,

1. Go to the [flagging tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools)
2. Flag one of the posts
3. Refresh page
4. Post is not excluded, as it used to.

> [image]

Comment: It will even show it to you if you're the one that flagged it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.

10k flag tools will not longer show you posts with active flags when first loading the page and when refreshing.

This is in the next build.

Comment: There still seems to be a glitch here. While they are not listed anymore, there's still a mention of them in the right column: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uIMqZ.png