# Flag queue counter is not getting refreshed after handling a post

Tags: bug, review, flags, 10k-tools

Ok so [duplicating flag in queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185981/173001) is successfully solved.

Now it is not displaying the duplicate posts but the counter of the post is not getting decreased. Meaning when I am handing a NAA flag and if it is showing me there 10 remaining NAA post, after handling 3 posts, it should show me 7 NAA flags remaining, but as per new changes applied, it is still showing the old counter as 10  NAA posts, here is the screen shot,

> [image]

As we can see that there is only three posts left for me out of 8 NAA post, but at the right side it is still showing me 8 instead of 3.

## Edit:

From the below image we can see that there is only one post left for me, but the counter is showing total 5 NAA posts left,

> [image]

Can we fix this counter as well ?

Comment: @hims056 Also on SO, the flagged duplicate is on Meta.