# No moderator flags, but count shows 1?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

There should be one flag according to the main navigation and the tabs, but there are none:

[image]

The title of the page says "0 moderator flags". What gives? Is there maybe a flag against one of my own posts?

Comment: Been having this problem lately too.

Comment: A kind of related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186036/173001

Comment: @Lucifer Please don't change the meaning of the post. The HTML `title` shows 0 flags.

Comment: Do you mean <HTML><TITLE> one ?

Comment: @Lucifer Yes – I'm curious as to what other titles you would think there are in HTML :)

Comment: I was looking at screen shot's title, I am mobile-app developer so not know much of web part `tag` things, sorry.

Comment: Cashing? When the new changes were being tested here on MSO the headline flag count never matched the actual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, since the close/flag changes we've has some... inconsistencies in which flags are counter where.

These are being ironed out where we find them. Sorry.

Comment: Just FYI, it now happens again for me.