# Flag counter varies wildly from actual flag count

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, top-bar

Now guyz, I know we like to cache stuff around here, but when I see a flag count this high;

[image]

... and upon clicking it, I actually see this;

> [image]

... I severely doubt caching is solely at play here; I'm aware that the flag count does not *exactly* match up due to caching and the like (and dupes exist to mention this); but this is a difference of ***78*** or, ***360%***.

I've been seeing this since the deploy of the new flagging system last week(ish).

Comment: They're probably all close flags. I noticed that they stopped appearing in the flag queue, probably because they can be handled by the Close Votes review task now (or maybe they're still supposed to appear, who knows)... Before, they usually accounted for the vast majority of all flags.

Comment: Yes I too marked this situation http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186036/173001

Comment: @hims056 That one's on Meta, this one's on SO.