# 10k tools have differing flag counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

I was in the 10k-tools and noticed that the flag count when I was on the Delete tab was 3:

[image: 3 flags]

Then when I clicked on the flags tab, it changed to 2:

[image: 2 flags]

Note, when I clicked back on it, even after some time the problem was still there, so I don't think it was necessarily a caching issue.

Comment: Doesn't just happen to be two the times you've clicked on it does it? :)

Comment: Huh, interesting. I can definitely reproduce this. Might have something to do with the "invalid flags" flags?

Comment: Same on SO: 203 vs 204. I doubt SO only has one 'invalid flag' though. -- No wait, at the time I write this SO does have exactly 1 invalid flag.

Comment: Partly related: [10k flag tools no longer exclude posts I've already reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185892/168244) and actually still not fully fixed... flags show even though they've been dealt with by the user.

Comment: reproduced, fixing...

Comment: Caching, it's always caching. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the number was cached only in the flags tab (that view is reused on the mod pages). Fixed version will include this cached version in all `/tools` tabs (build rev `2014.1.10.1839` on meta and `2014.1.10.1290` on sites)